# document.querySelectorAll not working in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a complete beginner so help me understand why document.querySelectorAll isn't working here?

```
   <p id="demo">This is a paragraph.</p>
   <h1 id="1demo"> Hello </h1>
   <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Set font size</button>

    <script>
       function myFunction() {
       document.querySelectorAll("#demo, #1demo").style.fontSize = "x-large";
        }
    </script>
```

I tried this with 'getElementsByClassName' as well with class="demo" for both and it only worked when I specified "demo"[0] or "demo"[1], but it didn't work for both when just "demo" was given.

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over the node list returned from `querySelectorAll` and apply styles individually to each element. Also id selectors starting with numbers do not work nicely with `querySelectorAll`, so I changed `1demo` to `demo2`.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const nodes = document.querySelectorAll("#demo, #demo2");
  nodes.forEach(node => node.style.fontSize = "x-large");
}
```

```html
<p id="demo">This is a paragraph.</p>
<h1 id="demo2"> Hello </h1>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Set font size</button>
```

Comment: I just tried this and it doesn't work either...

Comment: @27RedFox Did you actually call `myFunction`? BTW, "doesn't work" isn't a useful description of failure in both your question and comments. What doesn't work? Any error messages?

Comment: @Spender, I did call 'myFunction'. What I mean by "doesn't work" is there is no output. Here, I used a button, so clicking the button produces no change. The font size remains the same.

Comment: @27RedFox I've updated my answer with a running code sample, one of the issues was that one of ids started with a number.

Comment: Ohh right! I completely missed that error. Thanks. Can you also possibility try with 'getElementsByClassName' method as well? The second part of my question; I tried it but there was no output.

Comment: It's the same idea with `getElementsByClassName`. It returns a node list, which you'll need to iterate over.

Answer (score 0):

Because [document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) returns a list of nodes. You'll have to iterate through each element of that list in order to get access to each element's properties like `element.style.fontSize`.

In order to iterate you can have many approaches like the [for...of loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of), [Array.forEach method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) or any other iterative instruction that can adjust to your case.